# When truth or falsity are attributed to the liar sentence, is it a truth trope or a falsity trope that is attributed, rather than a Property of Truth?

Tags: truth, properties, tropes, indexicals

I was reading the SEP article on tropes and in a [section on semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tropes/#TropSema), it says:

[image]

So when we say, "This is a false sentence," is the initial attribution of falsity equivalent to the attribution of a falsity trope to/as "This"? And then, if we were to ask after the accuracy of the initial claim, when we [revision-theoretically](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-revision/) "hypothesize" about the claim, do we attribute a (further?) truth or falsity trope to the whole of, "This is a false sentence"?  So rather than there being a Property of Truth, or some one Truth Value of True, we would have a horde of truth tropes available variously for different true sentences/propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suppose any logical coherence of the metaphysical claims of truth, truth-aptness, and satisfiability related to tropes requires a statement of what a trope is. Reading the SEP (and not having read specifically a particular theory on tropes), **there is great variance on claims about what a trope is**. From the SEP article:

> **Apart from this very thin core assumption—that there are tropes—different trope theories need not have very much in common.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptualism)** Most trope theorists (but not all) believe that—fundamentally—there is nothing but tropes. Most trope theorists (but, again, not all) hold that resemblance between concrete particulars is to be explained in terms of resemblance between their respective tropes. (emphasis mine)

Let us, however, **presume that the trope of a truth-apt statement might be viewed as the epistemological judgement of the truth of some proposition P in some context C at some time T, and that with the passage of time context may vary, through the addition or subtraction of other truths related to C**. For instance, "I will die some day" seems to be a very good candidate for demonstrating that the truth of that statement might be associated with the judgement of it, and that the judgement varies greatly when one is 5 years old, 15 years old, 50 years old, and 100 years old. While the statement is, on a physicalist reading, always true, the judgment itself varies radically in its variance at various stages in the judge's life. Thus, there are subtle associations if one views the truth through a holophrastic lens.

So in this way, judgment, which is form of decision based on perception shows us **there are parallels to perceiving and deciding what a truth or a color is** since judgments in truth-aptness can vary in difficulty, can be illusory, and are constructed as experience by the mind in the same way color is perceived. This of course seems to require embracing a constructivist's epistemology. But like the application of tropes to spontaneous presentation of colors to simplify explanation, so too would truth-aptness being perceived as a trope benefit.

In this way, **elevating truth-aptness to trope above property can be seen as a superior construction because it helps harmonize theories of truth themselves**. Instead of being an external, essential property of a proposition, it makes the proposition an instrument by which experience is conveyed free of the curse of the God's eye view of the universe. Epistemological judgment becomes unavoidably contextual, but not 100% relative, because if people share contexts and the experience of contexts, then there is no problem of radical indeterminancy as Quine argues. That is, it seems to strike a fine balance between realist and anti-realist extremes in the spirit of intersubjectivity.

**Is there canonical agreement on such a position? Ha! I think not.** However, it seems wholly harmonious with modern interpretations of [conceptualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptualism). From WP:

> In metaphysics, conceptualism is a theory that explains universality of particulars as conceptualized frameworks situated within the thinking mind.[2] Intermediate between nominalism and realism, the conceptualist view approaches the metaphysical concept of universals from a perspective that denies their presence in particulars outside the mind's perception of them.[3] Conceptualism is anti-realist about abstract objects, just like immanent realism is (their difference being that immanent realism accepts there are mind-independent facts about whether universals are instantiated).

**Thus, to a conceptualist, the property of truth of P is particular to the judge and judgment, but is not in any sense universal.** In other words, it strikes a nice balance in the debate in universal and particulars. Truth-aptness is an abstraction over particular instances of truth, and allows truths, truth-aptness, and satisfiability to vary from thinker to thinker but allows for enough common ground to allow these constructs to be useful in communicating experience.

Comment: Wonderfully thought-provoking question.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it goes over a possible "mechanism" for truth tropes (the judgment process), which eventually fits into my dialogical approach to the liar paradox. Thank you for engaging with the question enough to see it through to such a reply!

Comment: Are you trying to invent your own dynamic semantics? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dynamic-semantics/

Comment: Oh... you mean this.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogical_logic?wprov=sfla1 Curiously, I came to it through a link to a programming language called PCF.